"Как не приду" или "как ни приду"? Верно ли решена задача?
                      Наш учитель Интернет...
                      Ну чего там только нет!

Вот тема: Как ни или как не. Ни или Не: Разгадываем Загадку Русской Орфографии
Один из примеров
«Как не приду» или «Как ни приду»: Время и Отрицание
Здесь ситуация несколько иная. Правильно писать «как не приду». В этом случае «не» указывает на отрицание действия. Фраза «как не приду» может быть частью предложения, обозначающего условие или ограничение. Например: «Пока я не приду, не начинайте». Здесь «не» отрицает действие «приду», определяя временной промежуток.
Вот заключение: Надеюсь, эта статья помогла вам разобраться в сложной, но интересной теме! Теперь вы сможете уверенно использовать «не» и «ни» в своей речи и на письме! Успехов!
ВОПРОСЫ
Все ли здесь верно?  Как бы вы ответили на этот вопрос: «Как не приду» или «Как ни приду»? Обе ли формы существуют, какие можно привести примеры?
Другие примеры тоже вызывают сомнения.
Дополнительный вопрос: Как правильно изучать эту тему, чтобы решать такие задачи быстро и быть уверенным в своих решениях? Нужны ли здесь правила, грамматика или обобщенный анализ ситуаций?
Какая методика предлагается в статье? Запомните эти выражения, чтобы не ошибаться! Это правило важно запомнить, чтобы избежать ошибок. Запишите его в свой блокнот или сделайте закладку на этой статье! Запомните этот нюанс!
Очень много предлагается выучить, записать, закладку сделать. Можно ли по этой теме запомнить самое необходимое?
P. S. Оформление статьи тоже не идеальное с точки зрения правописания.

Как ни приду - всякий раз когда прихожу.
